# Android: use res/values with String[]

Tags: android, android-resources

I know how to use strings.xml for global strings in Android, but what's about the String[] ?

Is there any possibility to use this and if there is, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant String arrays inside and xml refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Create a file in your values folder called `arrays.xml` and create your array like this

```
<string-array name="colors">
    <item>red</item>
    <item>orange</item>
    <item>yellow</item>
    <item>green</item>
    <item>blue</item>
    <item>violet</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not Directly in strings.xml, but something like this can be done in string.xml:

```
<string name="string1">str1</string>
<string name="string2">str2</string>

<string-array name="system">
    <item>@string/string1</item>
    <item>@string/string2</item>
</string-array>
```